# Are DHCPv6 Information-request messages via unicast permitted?

Tags: dhcp, dhcpv6

[RFC8415 section 16](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-16):

> A server **MUST discard** any Solicit, Confirm, Rebind, or
> **Information-request** messages it receives with a Layer 3 **unicast**
> destination address.

[RFC8415 section 18.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-18.4):

> For example, **unicast** transmission is not allowed for Solicit,
> Confirm, and Rebind messages (see Sections 18.3.1, 18.3.3, and
> 18.3.5, respectively), even if the Server Unicast option (see
> Section 21.12) is configured. For Request, Renew,
> **Information-request**, Release, and Decline messages, it **is allowed
> only if the Server Unicast option is configured**.

These statements contradict each other. Are unicast transmissions (after the receipt of a Server Unicast option) permitted or not?

Comment: It sure sounds like an error. You should [report it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/how-to-report/).